# Div is duplicated out of nowhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to build a site and Im having the issue where the site creates another div (DOM) but I cant figure out why. In my HTML file I have only 6 divs but once i go to my elements on my browser and I see a div duplicated. I dont believe i have any JS code that creates this div.All I have is existing code fade in and out rather than being replaced, hence no divs are created by my JS code.

**Duplicated Code**

```
    <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/middle.png" alt="" class="icons" id="middleID"></div>
```

**HTML CODE**
[image: HTML CODE]

**Elements from the browser**
[image: Elements from the browser]

```js
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
//the key strokes for the up and down keys

// Set up our container
var el = document.querySelector("#theMiddle");
// Create new SlotMachine
var slot = new SlotMachine(el, {});

var count = 0;
function remove() {
  if(count == 1){

  }else {
    $('#blankID').fadeOut("slow", function() {
      $('#aboutID').fadeIn("slow", function() {


      });
    });

      count++;

  }
}
function isOnScreen(){
  if (slot.visibleTile == 3) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function open() {
    anime({
        targets: "div.right",
        translateX: {
            value: 200,
            duration: 500
        }
    });
    anime({
        targets: "div.left",
        translateX: {
            value: -200,
            duration: 500
        }
    });
}

function close() {
    anime({
        targets: "div.right",
        translateX: {
            value: 0,
            duration: 500
        }
    });
    anime({
        targets: "div.left",
        translateX: {
            value: 0,
            duration: 500
        }
    });
}


document.onkeydown = checkKey;
function checkKey(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == "40") {
        //this is down
        //this will open it up
        open();
        slot.prev();
        if(isOnScreen()){
          close();
        }
    } else if (e.keyCode == "38") {
        open();
        console.log(isOnScreen());
        slot.next();
        if(isOnScreen()){
          close();
        }
    }
    remove();


}

//Scroll detection occurs here, without the scrollbar
$("html").on("mousewheel", function(e) {
    open();
    var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
    if (delta < 0) {
        //This is for the scrolling down
        // animation opens up the brakets
        slot.prev();
        if(isOnScreen()){
          close();
        }
    }
    if (delta > 0) {
        slot.next();
        if(isOnScreen()){
          close();
        }
    }
    remove();

});


//this is for detecting clicks  for the divs in the middle div
// 1 = the 2nd image , 2 = the  3rd image
$(".middle div").click(function() {
  if($(this).index() == '1'){
    console.log("lol");
  }

    if ($(this).index() == '2') {
        $('#theMiddle').fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $('#aboutTextID').fadeIn("slow", function() {});
            $("#backButtonID").fadeIn("slow", function() {});
            //Define the event handler here after the btn has been created
            $("#backButtonID").click(function() {
                console.log("back");
                $('#aboutTextID').fadeOut("slow", function() {
                    $("#backButtonID").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                        $('#theMiddle').fadeIn("slow", function() {});
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
    if ($(this).index() == '3') {
        $('#theMiddle').fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $('#applyButtonID').fadeIn("slow", function() {});
            $("#backButtonID").fadeIn("slow", function() {});
            //Define the event handler here after the btn has been created
            $("#backButtonID").click(function() {
                console.log("back");
                $('#applyButtonID').fadeOut("slow", function() {
                    $("#backButtonID").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                        $('#theMiddle').fadeIn("slow", function() {});
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.box{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 4px;
  display: inline-block;

}

div.left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 390px;
}

div.middle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 490px;
  top: 150px;
}

div.right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 870px;
}

#left,#right{
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#middle{
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
#theMiddle{
  left: 490px;
  top: 150px;
}
#foo {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  left: 490px;
  top: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll
}

#aboutTextID{
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  left: 490px;
  top: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll
}

.backButton{
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  height: 20px;
  width: 70px;
  left: 490px;
  top: 90px;
}
#applyButtonID{
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  height: 20px;
  width: 120px;
  left: 600px;
  top:200px;
}
#aboutID{
  display: none;

}
.icon-user-tie:before {
  content: "\e976";
}
.fa-map{
  color: #662c92;
  margin-left: 120px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Underscores</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" name="Back" class="backButton" id="backButtonID">Back</button>


  <div id= "left" class="left">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/images/left.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <p id='aboutTextID' >"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  </p>

<a id="applyButtonID" class="typeform-share button" href="https://bhagyeshpatel1.typeform.com/to/ytfEgw" data-mode="popup" style="text-decoration:none;background-color:#662c92;color:white;cursor:pointer;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:20px;line-height:50px;text-align:center;margin:0;height:50px;padding:0px 33px;border-radius:25px;max-width:100%;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;font-weight:bold;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;" \
target="_blank">Launch me </a>
<script> (function() {
  var qs,js,q,s,d=document, gi=d.getElementById, ce=d.createElement, gt=d.getElementsByTagName, id="typef_orm_share", b="https://embed.typeform.com/";
    if(!gi.call(d,id)){
      js=ce.call(d,"script");
      js.id=id;
      js.src=b+"embed.js";
      q=gt.call(d,"script")[0];
      q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q) }
    })()
</script>
  <div class="middle" id = "theMiddle" style="width: 400px; height: 300px">
    <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/middle.png" alt="" class="icons" id="middleID"></div>
    <div><i class="fas fa-map fa-10x" size = "100px" style="width: 400px; height: 300px">     </i></div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/job.png" alt="" class="icons" id="jobID"></div>
    <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/selectionIcon/About.png" alt="" class="icons" id="aboutID"></div>
    <div><img src="" alt="" class="icons" id="blankID" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div>
  </div>

  <div id= "right" class="right"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/underscores.xyz/images/right.png" alt=""></div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-slotmachine@4.0.0/dist/slotmachine.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="back.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try browsing your website in Incognito window? Probably some extension are running

Comment: @Chaska I tried in Incognito and another browser, still same issue

Comment: perhaps something in `var slot = new SlotMachine(el, {});` is duplicating the first div to the end - the name "SlotMachine" suggests that it would if it emulates a slot machine

Comment: what is the SlotMachine object?

Comment: If I were to write something that looked a bit like a slot machine, I would do exactly that - duplicate the first "slot" (or more than one depending on the display) and put the duplicate at the end, so that I could "roll" the entries properly

Comment: @rick its a library: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-slotmachine@4.0.0/dist/slotmachine.min.js

Comment: @JaromandaX yes it is

Comment: in that library `this._fakeLastTile = this.tiles[0].cloneNode(true);this.container.appendChild(this._fakeLastTile);` - as I said, if I were to emulate a slot machine, that's **exactly** what I'd do

Comment: @JaromandaX so its in the library?

Comment: yes, it's the library - and as I've been saying, that's exactly the kind of code you would expect for a slot machine emulation, so, while I didn't need to see the library to know this, at least now you can rest assured that you now know why it is happening - P.S. you'll want to remove the id for valid HTML as ID's need to be unique :p